# Suggestions for obtaining session persistence when using load-balanced MDM servers (iOS)

Tags: ios, network, mdm

It is not uncommon these days to have multiple back end servers and use some form of load-balancing between then.

When using such a configuration for MDM servers (that support the Apple MDM protocol), does Apple provide any guidelines or assistance in achieving session persistence? At present, it seems like the only option is to use persistence based on IP-address of the device. This may work in some cases but doesn't seem ideal.

As an example of something that could help, if it were possible to set custom cookies that were attached to outgoing MDM-related requests from the client, then it would be easy to achieve session persistence. But I have not seen any references to anything like this in Apple's documentation.

Comment: As a point of reference, how many clients are you supporting?

Comment: It may be several thousands, possibly tens of thousands.

Comment: OK. Well beyond my 600 or so devices. :-)